# How to download a file in bash from a download PHP script?

Tags: bash

How to download a file in bash from a download PHP script?

For example, a file named nerdtree.zip that can be download by running this link in browser:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=17123

Answer (score 2):

```
wget -O nerdtree.zip http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=17123
```

works for me. (I just *couldn't* leave this question be without a `wget` answer!)

Comment: So it's all on: wget vs curl. Who gets the tick? Not that it's a competition. But I'll win. ;)

Comment: @stib Perhaps I should add a `bash` entry to make my chances of winning go up. :) `exec 5<>/dev/tcp/www.example.com/80; echo GET /...` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -o output.zip http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=17123
```

works for me.